# How to work with binary contraints in linear optimization?

Tags: r, optimization

I have two input matrices, dt(10,3) & wt(3,3), that i need to use to find the optimal decision matrix (same dimension), Par(10,3) so as to maximize an objective function. Below R code would give some direction into the problem (used Sample inputs here) -

```
#Input Matrices
dt <- matrix(runif(300),100,3) 
wt <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1),3,3) #weights

#objective function    
Obj <- function(Par) {
   P = matrix(Par, nrow = 10, byrow=F) # Reshape
   X = t((dt%*%wt)[,1])%*%P[,1]
   Y = t((dt%*%wt)[,2])%*%P[,2]
   Z = t((dt%*%wt)[,3])%*%P[,3]
   as.numeric(X+Y+Z) #maximize
   }
```

Now I am struggling to apply the following constraints to the problem :

```
1) Matrix, Par can only have binary values (0 or 1)
2) rowSums(Par) = 1 (Basically a row can only have 1 in one of the three columns) 
3) colSums(Par[,1]) <= 5, colSums(Par[,2]) <= 6, & colSums(Par[,3]) <= 4
4) X/(X+Y+Z) < 0.35, & Y/(X+Y+Z) < 0.4 (X,Y,Z are defined in the objective function)
```

I tried coding the constraints in constrOptim, but not sure how to input binary & integer constraints. I am reading up on lpSolve, but not able to figure out. Any help much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Binary variables are only possible if the solver supports these. This is typically done within a convex-optimization setting (Mixed-integer, Mixed-QP, Mixed-QCQP, Mixed-SOCP; and only some research-solvers can solve Mixed-SDPs). In a non-convex setting there is not much more than Couenne & Knitro (and the problem is very hard). constrOptim / optim cannot do this! lpSolve can only do this for MIPs. As i'm not that familiar with R, i can't reason about the convexity of your problem. But if X,Y,Z are variables (not constants), it looks bad regarding convexity!

Comment: Hi Sascha,
Thanks for the response. Appreciate your time. I am not too familiar with different optimization settings. Based on Erwin's response, I coded using lpSolve and able to frame the model (struggling with one constraint). Although I am worried about processing now as I have to run this on a million records. I may have to look for options other than R that can handle such data. Any thoughts on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is indeed a MIP so no issues with convexity. If I am correct the model can look like:

[image]

This model can be easily transcribed into R. Note that LP/MIP solvers do not use functions for the objective and constraints (opposed to NLP solvers). In R typically one builds up matrices with the LP coefficients.

Note: I had to make the limits on the column sums much larger (I used 50,60,40).

Comment: Thanks Erwin for formulating the model. I appreciate your time. I am able to transcribe most of the above using lpSolve (a MIP solver) in R. still struggling to apply the constraints on xlim & ylim (4th constraint in my problem above). As this constraint is dependent on the objective function/values(X/Obj <= 0.35, etc), I am not sure how to add this constraint in the model. I have shared the code below. It would be great if you can guide from here. Thanks!

Comment: I added variables w and z to the model to do those.

Comment: Finally able to code the 4th constraint. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Erwin's response, I am able to formulate the model using lpSolve in R. However still struggling to add the final constraint to the model (4th constraint in my question above). Here's what I am able to code so far :

```
#input dimension
r <- 10
c <- 3

#input matrices
dt <- matrix(runif(r*c),r,c)
wt <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1),3,3) #weights

#column controller
c.limit <- c(60,50,70)

#create structure for lpSolve
ncol <- r*c
lp.create <- make.lp(ncol=ncol)
set.type(lp.create, columns=1:ncol, type = c("binary"))

#create objective values 
obj.vals <- as.vector(t(dt%*%wt))
set.objfn(lp.create, obj.vals) 
lp.control(lp.create,sense='max')

#Add constraints to ensure sum of parameters for every row (rowSum) <= 1
for (i in 1:r){
 add.constraint(lp.create, xt=c(1,1,1),
             indices=c(3*i-2,3*i-1,3*i), rhs=1, type="<=")
}

#Add constraints to ensure sum of parameters for every column (colSum) <= column limit (defined above)
for (i in 1:c){
 add.constraint(lp.create, xt=rep(1,r),
             indices=seq(i,ncol,by=c), rhs=c.limit[i], type="<=")
}

#Add constraints to ensure sum of column objective (t((dt%*%wt)[,i])%*%P[,i) <= limits defined in the problem)
#NOT SURE HOW TO APPLY A CONSTRAINT THAT IS DEPENDENT ON THE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION

solve(lp.create)
get.objective(lp.create) #20
final.par <- matrix(get.variables(lp.create), ncol = c, byrow=T) # Reshape
```

Any help that can get me to the finish line is much appreciated :)

Thanks